# Heroku to AWS Migration Advice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, amazon-web-services, heroku, paas

From what i've gathered, there are many solutions to my problem but i'd appreciate some suggestions on where to start. here's the stack we're running on heroku currently:

- Rails on puma
- mongoDB
- elasticsearch
- redis
- mini_magick

What goes into the decision of using Elastic Beanstalk vs OpsWorks vs CloudFormation vs just setting up everything manually myself? Also, I'd really prefer, for financial reasons, not to use some third party service like Docker if possible. The plethora of options leaves me a little confused as to where to begin or how to even choose. Background: right now I really like Heroku b/c i don't have to think too much about sysadmin (on my team i'm the only developer), but we were recently given a lot of annual AWS credits so it seems to make financial sense for us to shift over to AWS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your Rails app, Elastic Beanstalk is going to be very similar to Heroku. I would suggest using Elastic Beanstalk if you are already familiar with a PaaS like Heroku. It's probably going to be a bit more difficult to configure at first (there are just a lot more options you can configure), but then it will be a very similar deployment process to what you are used to.

Of course Heroku and most (probably all) of those other services you are using run on top of AWS already, so you would really just be switching from one set of services built on AWS to Amazon's own version of those services. You could possibly continue using some of the same services you are using on Heroku. For example I believe MongoLab is the recommended service for MongoDB on Heroku, and it is my preferred MongoDB-as-a-Service on AWS as well. If you want to use those AWS credits for MongoDB you will have to setup the EC2 servers and install and manage MongoDB yourself.

For Redis you could use Amazon's ElastiCache service or RedisLabs. I've found the features and price to be better with RedisLabs than ElastiCache, but you can use your AWS credits with ElastiCache.

For Elasticsearch you would probably want to use Amazon's new managed Elasticsearch service.

Comment: thanks @mbaird! this sounds like the sort of setup that i was starting to converge towards after all my reading, but it helps a lot to get some confirmation... i'm curious, do you have any go-to sources for learning other than amazon's own documentation? their documentation only takes you so far

Answer (score 6):

I want to expand on Mark’s great answer.

## Available alternatives

Since you’re the sole developer, Cloud Formation and OpsWorks aren’t good options for you.

With OpsWorks you’ll need to write, or at least be aware of, the Chef automation code that configures your instances. On the other hand, Cloud Formation by itself isn’t enough. It will help you with AWS cloud resources creations, but you will still need to figure out how to orchestrate your applications deployment, just for starters. 
Neither of these options can give you everything you need to run and deploy your code like Heroku does right out of the box. You’ll need to implement parts of it by yourself.

Since rolling your own automation on top of EC2 takes even more effort than the options above, I think you have two alternatives within AWS that will fit your needs:

#### 1) Elastic Beanstalk

It’s the closest you can get to Heroku within AWS. You might have to spend some time getting to know the platform at first since it’s not as intuitive as Heroku, but eventually Elastic Beanstalk will provide you with all the tools you need to continue running your applications without spending time on sysadmin tasks.

#### 2) ECS + Empire

Although you mentioned that using Docker is out of question for you, I still would like to highlight the option of using ECS, Amazon’s Docker orchestration service, as an alternative to Heroku.

By itself, ECS doesn’t provide enough automation to do everything you would expect from a PaaS. The service was intended to be used as a building block which you should extend to fit your needs.

Luckily, the guys from Remind have already done this for you. They have released an open source project called [Empire](http://engineering.remind.com/introducing-empire/), which according to its own description is “a control layer on top of ECS that provides a Heroku-like workflow”.

Empire is compatible with Heroku’s API, and its command line implements the most important features of Heroku.

Empire is an open source project, so if you choose to use it, you should be prepared to dig into its code from time to time. The documentation isn’t perfect, and although there is some traction around the project, the community isn’t very big.

Overall, it’s a good alternative to Heroku if you’re willing to run your applications using Docker -- and why shouldn’t you?

## Addons

The main benefit I see to switching from Redis Labs to Amazon’s Redis service (ElastiCache), other than the fact that you have free AWS credit, is that it’s going to be easier (and cheaper) to secure access to your Redis instances when you also run your applications on AWS.

Overall, it’s relatively easy to replicate the addons you’re using with Heroku when you migrate to AWS. For the third-party addons like Elasticsearch you just continue pointing your application to the relevant endpoint. It’s a bit more complicated to replicate Heroku’s native addons like deploy hooks since you can’t continue to use them when you migrate to AWS. In these cases it’s usually possible to find alternative ways of replicating their functionality within AWS.

If you want to learn about how to migrate the most common addons, I’ve written an article that details how to do that, you can find it here: [how to replicate Heroku’s addons on AWS](http://opsfleet.com/topics/migrate-from-heroku-to-aws/addons-migration/).

Hope this helps.